# Independent solutions to $\sin(\theta) = -\sin(\phi)$ and $\cos(\theta) = -\cos(\phi)$

Tags: trigonometry, proof-verification

The equation
$$
\sin(\theta) = \sin(\phi)
$$
has the set of solutions
$$
\big\{\, (\theta, \phi) \in \mathbb{R}^{2} : \theta - \phi \equiv 0 \,\,\mathrm{(mod}\,\,2\pi) \hspace{10pt}\text{or}\hspace{10pt} \theta + \phi \equiv \pi \,\,\mathrm{(mod}\,\,2\pi) \,\big\},\tag{$1$}
$$
and similarly the equation
$$
\cos(\theta) = \cos(\phi)
$$
has the set of solutions
$$
\big\{\, (\theta, \phi) \in \mathbb{R}^{2} : \theta \pm \phi \equiv 0 \,\,\mathrm{(mod}\,\,2\pi) \,\big\}.\tag{$2$}
$$

The solution set $(1)$ [can be written equivalently](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-solution-of-sinx-siny) as
$$
\theta = n\pi + (−1)^{n}\phi
$$
for some integer $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

> I am similarly trying to find the solutions to the (separate) equations
>   $$
> \sin(\theta) = -\sin(\phi) \quad\text{and}\quad \cos(\theta) = -\cos(\phi)
> $$
>   in terms of $\theta$ and $\phi$.

#### Workings

Since $\sin$ is an odd function,
$$
\sin(\theta) = -\sin(\phi) = \sin(-\phi)
$$
has the set of solutions
$$
\big\{\, (\theta, \phi) \in \mathbb{R}^{2} : \theta + \phi \equiv 0 \,\,\mathrm{(mod}\,\,2\pi) \hspace{10pt}\text{or}\hspace{10pt} \theta - \phi \equiv \pi \,\,\mathrm{(mod}\,\,2\pi) \,\big\}\tag{3}
$$
by substituting $-\phi$ in place of $\phi$ in $(1)$.

By drawing key points on the cosine graph, the set of solutions to the cosine equation is
$$
\big\{\, (\theta, \phi) \in \mathbb{R}^{2} : \theta \pm \phi \equiv \pi \,\,\mathrm{(mod}\,\,2\pi) \,\big\}.\tag{4}
$$
I would like some clarification that this is correct. I have checked them numerically for a range of values, and it is sensible that these should be the answers.

Comment: Seems correct to me.

Comment: Looks fine now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your equations say that
$$e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta=-(\cos\phi+i\sin\phi)=-e^{i\phi}=e^{i(\phi+\pi)}\ .$$
This is true iff $$\theta-\phi=(2n+1)\pi,\qquad n\in{\mathbb Z}\ .$$